# Where can I find this kind of control for making Electronic album on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Now I am making a Electronic album on iPad and I want to show the photos like this:

[image]

I have no idea where I can find this kind of control . Does any one know it or some places that I can find it? Really thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel).  I've posted a link to the author's github repository, since you seem to be having a problem going in via Cocoa Controls.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Carousel class: http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/icarousel

Comment: seems can not open it ~~

Answer (score 0):

You might try taking a look around cocoacontrols.com.  Do a search for coverflow there.  This one looks like it might be a good starting place: http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/icarousel

Answer (score 0):

`https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary`   u can make a coverflow like feature with this library